# Jquery .html() seems not update JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load a template from an ajax call(and I put that content inside a div using `.html()`). This template has  and some divs.

The problem is that I receive the correct JS from that call, but it seems that .html() does not update the `<script>`. I have:

```
<div id="val">
   <script>....</script>
</div>
```

when I do: $('#val').html(contentFromAJAX), the JS is not loaded correctly.
How can i do?

**EDIT:** with "not loaded correctly", I mean that the previous `<script>` inside that div remain there, .html() seems do not change it.

Comment: what is not working are you sure you have something in the variable? http://jsfiddle.net/ue44U/ do you want to execute the returned content as JavaScript? or add some JavaScript to the DOM?

Comment: im confused... are you recieving html or js from the ajax call?? for js try text() instead of html()

Comment: @ZolaKt, I'm receiving a template....this template has <script> and <div>

Comment: @gordatron: i dont think that is important, even if the variable is empty it should replace the old html

Comment: @Dail: what kind of template? there are many templates... post the sample return from the call

Answer (score 1):

Set the dataType of your ajax call: `dataType: "script"`

Or use the [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)